# Using TextBox in Email Template to Get User input

Tags: php, html, html-email, newsletter, mailchimp

I am coding Mailchimp Template, what I have to do is  add a Text box in Email template and the one who receives  email will enter some value in text box and press  send button in email, and entered value will be sent to my email address as email, I know very well how to code mailchimp templates but really have no idea to add textbox and gets its value and send to my email account Please guide me how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a HTML form with a POST or GET action that sends the data to a server, then from there you can email the value to yourself. You cannot rely on the viewer's computer to send the email.

Comment: will it be exactly as  php contact form ?

Comment: Forms inside emails? Most of the clients will probably remove them.

Comment: @EduardLuca not complete form , i have to take usre input for  1 field using Mailchimp .  have a look  [http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/](http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/)    but i dont believe this will work

Comment: @Sikander look at the support chart. Many don't support forms, and some display warnings. If you're OK with that, that definitely the tutorial you should follow.

Comment: Here is a [support chart from Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/resources/will-it-work/forms/)